# How can I write an alias for cd such that it will fire ls after going into the directory to which I just cd'ed into?

Tags: linux, ls, alias, cd-command

Lets say I want to do `cd home` and then `ls -lrth`. I want these two things combined into a single command. I tried writing an alias, but it didnt work. Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you show us alias you tried but it didn't work?

Comment: alias cd='cd; ls -lrth' didnt work :(

Comment: It works for me. It changes directory to `~` and executes `ls -lrth`. What shell do you use?

Comment: Bash. It tells me 'ls -  cannot stat <directory name>

Comment: .bashrc: export A=$PWD; export PROMPT_COMMAND='if [[ $A != "$PWD" ]];then A=$PWD; ls -l $PWD; fi'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using bash try to put this in your bashrc/bash_profile:

```
alias cd='cd $1 && ls -lrth'
```

UPDATE:

This is not correct, i just double checked it, it is just listing the dir you did want to cd in but it stays in your actual dir where you launched the command.

UPDATE 2:

You have to create a bash function instead of an alias it is much safer than overriding a built in command.

```
cdd() {
     cd "$1" && ls -lhtr;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Yep. Even the bash man page itself recommends using functions instead of aliases. Aliases should only be used for the simplest things. My rule of thumb when creating aliases: "If at first you don't succeed, give up and write a function." :)

Comment: And if you want to call the function `cd` (which I **don't** recommend), you can do `cd(){ command cd "$1";ls -lrth; }`. The `command` builtin suppresses shell function lookup, so the function doesn't die in a recursive death spiral.

Comment: Ah good to know i never gave a function the same name like a built in because i was not sure what would happen and i was too afraid to test ;)

Comment: :) Definitely don't test stuff like that in your ~/.bashrc, do it in a shell so it'll die when you reboot.

Comment: Oops! I just noticed I accidentally put `;` instead of `&&` in my example. It _should_ be `cd(){ command cd "$1" && ls -lrth; }`